# Django restframework not working when called from different address

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently following the tutorial on: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ to create a restful API for my django app, hosted on apache. Then I want to call the api using ajax and show the data on my page.

Using the same code from the tutorial in url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets

# Serializers define the API representation.
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff')

# ViewSets define the view behavior.
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

And the ajax code to call api:

```
(function() {
var monsterAPI = "http://10.0.106.14/api/monsters/?format=json";

alert("DEBUG1");
$.getJSON( monsterAPI, {
 format: "json"
})
.done(function( monsters ) {
  alert("DEBUG2");

});
})();
```

When I call this ajax code from html hosted on the same apache server (//10.0.106.14/temp/) it works and I get alert "DEBUG2".
But when I call the api from html run from local server from different machine (//127.0.0.1/temp/) it reached "DEBUG1" and stopped.

Is there anything I missed out? :(

adding authentication and permission on settings.py does not solve the problem too:

```
 REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
    # 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    #     'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    #     'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    # ]
 }
```

Comment: What error do you get in your browsers console?

Comment: @limelights, there is no error. it just does not reach the code 'alert("DEBUG2")'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to access 127.0.0.1:8899 from 127.0.0.1 (default port 80) you may be hitting a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing issue.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#cors explains better than I would do about this topic and provides a workaround for this.

Comment: It works! after installing "django-cors-headers" from the URL you given. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand your description, you should specify port in your get-request. If you start server on port `8899`, you should request "http://127.0.0.1:8899/users/?format=json"

Comment: thank you for the prompt reply! but I want to call it from different url from the origin. if i call "http://127.0.0.1:8899/users/?format=json" from "http://127.0.0.1:8899/temp", it works